# Is Git Push same as Pull request

Tags: git

I am new to Git. After I commit my local changes, I create Pull request to merge change to remote branch. The issue is even after the PR is approved and merged, in my local git I keep getting 
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/X' by xxx commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. you don't create pull request to merge changes from your local to your remote branch. What you did is "Git push". [Git Pull and push tutorial](https://yangsu.github.io/pull-request-tutorial/). The pull is generally used between various branches in git.  Eg: Merge code in Branch A to B and so forth. Git push - typically refers to pushing the local code changes to a specific branch in git. Eg: You have modified fileA.txt in your local dev env. When you want this code to be in your development branch you push this code using git push;

- Note: Always use git pull to get the latest code from master before you compare branches.

Please take a look at the tutorial link. If you have doubts, rephrase the question with more explanation, please.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the difference between Git Pull and Push. What I meant is I went to the remote repo and created a pull request to get the changes from my local branch. The Pull request is approved and changes got merged to remote repo. But still, in my local if I run a Git Status, it still shows "You are ahead of Origin\X by xx commits.  What am I missing?

Comment: Your local branch when you push it should be present in the remote repository. Did you create a Pull request from that branch to the master branch ?

Comment: Yes. And in the remote master that use, I see my commits as well in the History tab. But in local command prompt, If I do git status I see the message "You are ahead.. ". That is confusing me

Comment: You would find the commits in the history. Is your pull request reviewed and approved for merging into the master. Unless it's approved, it won't be in the master branch.

Comment: Let's say your code has been merged in master branch. Before the time your code got merged, some other people's code could also have been merged. But those changes have nothing to do with your code. So when you give your PR it wont show it as a merge conflict.  These commits made by others are not in your branch and hence it will show as " you are ahead of XX commits".  This is the expected behavior.

Comment: To correct this - you can either pull the latest from master and create a new branch and push your code on top of it or you can cherry pick all the other commits that are to be in place before your commit. Since you are a beginner I would recommend you to take the first route.